# In Ruby what is the difference between different rescue statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby what is the difference between

```
def run
 begin
   raise SomeError.new
 rescue SomeError
   handle
 end    
end
```

and

```
def run
  raise SomeError.new
rescue SomeError
  handle
end
```

Comment: See http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html *"If you are inside a method you do not need to use `begin` ..."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:**

```
begin
  # something which might raise an exception
rescue SomeExceptionClass => some_variable
  # code that deals with some exception
ensure
  # ensure that this code always runs
end
```

Here, `def` as a `begin` statement:

```
def
  # something which might raise an exception
rescue SomeExceptionClass => some_variable
  # code that deals with some exception
ensure
  # ensure that this code always runs
end
```

Basically there is no difference. In above code method `def` can serve as a `begin` statement:

As spickermann commented You can also use `else`  that is only run if there wasn't an expection

```
begin  
  # -  
rescue OneTypeOfException  
  # -  
rescue AnotherTypeOfException  
  # -  
else  
  # Other exceptions  
end
```

For each `rescue` clause in the `begin` block, Ruby compares the raised Exception against each of the parameters in turn. The match will succeed if the exception named in the `rescue` clause is the same as the type of the currently thrown exception, or is a superclass of that exception. The code in an **`else`** clause is executed if the code in the body of the begin statement runs to completion without exceptions. If an exception occurs, then the `else` clause will obviously not be executed.

Refer this for more understanding: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html

Comment: You might also want to add `else`  that is only run if there wasn't an expection.

Answer (score 1):

The are same, no difference. The second is the shorthand of the first.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the 2 code you asked.  The only time you'd like to use `begin` though is if you only want a certain part of your code to be rescued.

```
def rescue_me
  no_rescue = 1 + 1

  begin
    no_rescue / 0
  rescue
    # handle
  end
end
```

It's also a good reminder to not just use `rescue`.  You should have an idea of what exception you want to rescue.  In the example above, you'd want to rescue `ZeroDivisionError`.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent, even if they do not generate identical code. Most of the changes are just renumberings, but there are a couple of extra instructions in the first one (labeled by `-` in this unified diff). They do not do much though (mainly `trace` and labels).

```
 ["YARVInstructionSequence/SimpleDataFormat", 2, 2, 1,
  {:arg_size=>0, :local_size=>1, :stack_max=>4},
  "<compiled>", "<compiled>", nil, 1, :top, [], {}, [],
  [1,
   [:trace, 1],
   [:putspecialobject, 1],
   [:putspecialobject, 2],
   [:putobject, :run],
   [:putiseq,
    ["YARVInstructionSequence/SimpleDataFormat", 2, 2, 1,
     {:arg_size=>0, :local_size=>1, :stack_max=>2},
     "run", "<compiled>", nil, 1, :method, [], {},
     [[:rescue,
       ["YARVInstructionSequence/SimpleDataFormat", 2, 2, 1,
        {:arg_size=>0, :local_size=>2, :stack_max=>2},
        "rescue in run", "<compiled>", nil, 2, :rescue, [:"\#$!"], {}, [],
-       [4,
-        [:trace, 1],
+       [3,
         [:getlocal_OP__WC__0, 2],
-        [:getinlinecache, :label_11, 0],
+        [:getinlinecache, :label_9, 0],
         [:getconstant, :SomeError],
         [:setinlinecache, 0],
-        :label_11,
+        :label_9,
         [:checkmatch, 3],
-        [:branchunless, :label_21],
-        5,
+        [:branchunless, :label_19],
+        4,
         [:trace, 1],
         [:putself],
         [:opt_send_without_block, {:mid=>:handle, :flag=>280, :blockptr=>nil, :orig_argc=>0}],
-        4,
+        3,
         [:leave],
-        :label_21,
+        :label_19,
         0,
         [:getlocal_OP__WC__0, 2],
         [:throw, 0]]],
-      :label_4,
-      :label_18,
-      :label_19,
+      :label_2,
+      :label_16,
+      :label_17,
       0],
-     [:retry, nil, :label_18, :label_19, :label_4, 0]],
+     [:retry, nil, :label_16, :label_17, :label_2, 0]],
     [1,
      [:trace, 8],
+     :label_2,
      2,
      [:trace, 1],
-     :label_4,
-     3,
-     [:trace, 1],
      [:putself],
-     [:getinlinecache, :label_14, 0],
+     [:getinlinecache, :label_12, 0],
      [:getconstant, :SomeError],
      [:setinlinecache, 0],
-     :label_14,
+     :label_12,
      [:opt_send_without_block, {:mid=>:new, :flag=>256, :blockptr=>nil, :orig_argc=>0}],
      [:opt_send_without_block, {:mid=>:raise, :flag=>264, :blockptr=>nil, :orig_argc=>1}],
-     :label_18,
-     2,
+     :label_16,
      [:nop],
-     :label_19,
-     7,
+     :label_17,
+     5,
      [:trace, 16],
-     3,
+     2,
      [:leave]]]],
   [:opt_send_without_block,
    {:mid=>:"core#define_method", :flag=>256, :blockptr=>nil, :orig_argc=>3}],
   [:leave]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, there is no difference except that option 1 looks uglier,

rescue applies to a code context, by placing a `begin...end` you create a code context to which `rescue` applies,

the second option works is because a method `def...end` is a code context too

Answer (score 0):

Both are same things with different syntax. Later is used to rescue a whole method instead of code block.

Answer (score 0):

IT looks both are same. In second code it gives you more code.